# Compare data collected with jquery each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

What I want to do is compare each element offset to each other and get the one that is closer to the top of the window, then  do something with that specific element

```
$(".slide").each(function(index, el) {
   var $this = $(this);
   var offset = $this.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

so basically, if I print the offset via `console.log` and I have for each element having the `slide` class,

I currently get these values :

```
slide1 = -875
slide2 = 250
slide2 = 850
slide4 = 1375
```

Slide 2 is the one currently closest to 0 so slide 2 would be the div I would want to do something with...

Hope i am clear enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were already quite close from your goal

```
var found=null;
var found_top=0;
$(".slide").each(function(index, el) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var offset = $this.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
    if( ( found == null ) || ( ( offset >= 0 ) && ( offset < found_top ) ) ){
        found=this;
        found_top=offset:
    }
});
/** do something with found here **/
```

Comment: I really have to go to bed, i'll test this code out tomorrow, but just by looking at it the light bulb light up, so I'm pretty sure it will work thank you

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but yes, this totally worked, thank you!